# What's wrong in this script?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I submit the form and I try to get the Roomsno input value its showing like
this-

`Array ( [0] => 1,2 );` why???

How can I send it so that it will come as a real array means like this-
**Array([0]=>1 [1]=>2)**

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="Roomsno" id="Roomsno" required>

<script>
    var rmidarray = []; //  new Array()
    var rmnoarray = [];

    $('.roomtype').change(function() {

      roomss_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
      no_room = $(this).val();

      var check = rmidarray.includes(roomss_id);

      if (check == true) {
        // alert('hi')
        index = rmidarray.indexOf(roomss_id);
        // alert(index);
        rmnoarray.splice(index, 1, no_room);

        // rmnoarray[index].push(no_room);
      } else if (check == false) {
        // alert('by');
        rmidarray.push(roomss_id);
        rmnoarray.push(no_room);
      } else {
        alert('No rooms Selected!!!')
      }


      $("#Roomsno").val(rmnoarray);

    });

   </script>
```

Comment: You can use multiple input elements (or one select with multiple selected options).

Comment: try to remove `[ ]` from `name="Roomsno[]"` and check again

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update with relevant HTML and other scripts to make a [mcve]

Comment: Also why make a hidden field required and readonly?

Comment: When removing [] from name=Roomsno it gives output like 1,2,4, so how can i send so it will come like Array([0]=>1[1]=>2[2]=>3)

Comment: And i dont think my question is any how related to making an input hidden and readonly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the value is in array format so Rather than setting the value directly use jason.stringfy- 
Ex.

```
$("#Roomsno").val(rmnoarray); //Instead of this one
$('#Roomsno').val(JSON.stringify(rmnoarray)); //This one worked for me
```

---

And when i try to get the value i use json.decode and the value will come as array and we can use it normally as we use array.  The array will come like- Array([0]=>1[1]=>2)